# Retrieve only given words from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working on boolean queries for example:

```
Information mining AND retrieval OR position
```

I want to create two arrays or lists, one that contains terms (terms can have capital letters) Terms can have phrasal queries i.e more than one word.

```
{Information mining, retrieval, position}
```

and second array would contain keywords

```
{AND, OR}
```

so I can map relevant search terms with their boolean operators.

I've created first array by using regex "AND | NOT | OR"
I can't figure out a way to create the second array from given string.

What regex can I use to achieve the result?

Comment: Instead of splitting use `Matcher#find`.

Comment: Read about [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

Comment: @Pshemo I looked it up and it returns only boolean value. I need an array. Is there a way to get an array using Matcher class?

Comment: Take a look at [regex tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), especially this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html to see how to use matcher to see founded part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
([A-Z][a-z\s]+)|([A-Z]+)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^--- Capture wey words
      +--- Capture regular words
```

**[Regex Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dE0iH9/1)**

**[Java demo example](https://ideone.com/C6mb7T)**

As you can see below, your group 1 will capture the words while the group 2 will capture the keywords.

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-11]  `information`
MATCH 2
2.  [12-15] `AND`
MATCH 3
1.  [16-25] `retrieval`
MATCH 4
2.  [26-28] `OR`
MATCH 5
1.  [29-37] `position`
```

Comment: Problem is terms can have capital letters too, for example "Information AND retrieval AND Position". Sorry if that wasn't clear. I will update my question.

Comment: @Xoul you can use this regex then `([A-Z]?[a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)`

Comment: Forgot to mention that terms can have phrasal queries as well, i.e more than one word. This is why I can't use a simple space delimited separator.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.